# Encapsulate thread function with boost bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-bind

I am currently creating boost::threads like this:

```
  boost::thread m_myThread; //member variable
  //...
  m_myThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::myThreadFunction, this));
```

This will start a thread which executes a member function "myThreadFunction".

I would like to encapsulate the starting of a new thread and use something like

```
boost::thread m_myThread; //member variable
//...
startAThread(&m_myThread, boost::bind(&MyClass::myThreadFunction, this), 123 /*some int argument*/);
```

I thought I could implement "startAThread" like this:

```
namespace internal
{
    template <typename Callable>
    void threadhelper(Callable func, int x)
    {
        doSomething(x);
        func();
    }
}
template <typename Callable>
void startAThread(boost::thread* threadToCreate, Callable func, int x)
{

    *threadToCreate = boost::thread(boost::bind(internal::threadhelper<Callable>, func, x));
}
```

However, this fails to compile with

```
usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In member function 'void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = void (*)(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, int), A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, A2 = boost::_bi::value<int>]':
usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:   instantiated from 'typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void, F = void (*)(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, int), L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, boost::_bi::value<int> >]'
usr/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:61:   instantiated from 'void boost::detail::thread_data<F>::run() [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, void (*)(boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, int), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >, boost::_bi::value<int> > >]'
MyClass.cpp:160:   instantiated from here
usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, MyClass>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<MyClass*> > >' requested
```

What does this error mean? What's wrong with the code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should also add the call to `createThreadWithPriority` (or is it the call to `startAThread` above?) -- A simple thing that is wrong is that you are not passing `func` down from `createThreadWithPriority` to `internal::threadhelper`.

Comment: of course, you're right. These were two mistakes a made when preparing the code for the posting. Now it should correspond to the code that I actually have.

Comment: If you ask about a compiler problem you are having, you should always post code that replicates the problem, and try to help others in reading the error messages in as much as possible. In particular, there is no indication in the code as to where MyClass.cpp line 160 is. (I am assuming that there is no errors before the ones you point to). I don't know if even with that info this can be easily answered, so I would try to create a test that is as similar to your code as possible and get it to fail in the same way (start from removing boost::thread from the equation).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
namespace internal
{
    template <typename Callable>
    void threadhelper(Callable func, int x)
    {
        doSomething(x);
        func();
    }
}
template <typename Callable>
void startAThread(boost::thread& threadToCreate, Callable func, int x) {        
    threadToCreate = boost::thread(boost::bind(&internal::threadhelper<Callable>, func, x));
}
```

I also used reference instead of pointer.